# SQL Where clause: all fields equal, except one

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, distinct, where-clause

Can i get an entries, which is equal in all the fields, except defined?

E.G.:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM table_name a 
INNER JOIN table_name b 
   on (a.price = b.price 
   AND a.quantity = b.quantity 
   AND {all the remaining params}) 
   AND a.id <> b.id
```

I need to find identical entries, except its ID (duplicate entries)

Comment: _all the remaining params_ You have to set all remaining params. You could use an automization such as a function that builds all the params

Comment: With a `minus` or `intersect` operators it ***may*** be possible, but MySQL doesn't support those functions.  So I would have to say, "No you can't"

Comment: Why your last condition is not included in the ON clause ?

Comment: @bub not that convinient, as if there would be native solution. Still got a point tho

Comment: @BeS uhm, it is, just for the readability "except condition" was moved out of the bracket

Comment: There is a different approach using a group by but you have to list all the fields.

Comment: You probably want a semi join (`IN` or `EXISTS`), not an `INNER JOIN` anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SELECT` with a `GROUP BY` clause.
For example, if you have a table called `names`, with a column `name`, which you want to check for duplicates. You can do:

```
select name, count(*) c from names group by name having c > 1;
```

This will also return an additional column indicating the number of times the duplicate value occurred in the rows.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the only way I can think of to find the duplicates but he would have to list all X fields individually in the select and group by. (Note: you could use system tables to generate the entire list of columns so you don't have to manually type them!)

Answer (score -1):

Change your "AND a.id <> b.id" to "WHERE a.id <> b.id" and that should work for you.

Comment: Re-read the question.  If a table has 30 columns he wants to compare 29 of them and make sure the 30th's doesn't match; but not list all the columns...

Comment: xQbert - changing the last AND to WHERE would select records from the joined tables where the id's are different, which is what he was looking for.

Comment: How would we know all the other fields are equal if they were not all defined? Bub says "you have to list them" in comments and Sly_huh indicates that it is "not convinient,"  ***Making it a where clause has no effect on the results when an INNER join is being used .**

Comment: I'm assuming {all the remaining params} means that he is equating all the fields in table 'a'  to their corresponding fields in table 'b'

Comment: Not needed, All about education here. I wasn't trying to be gruff (I didn't downvote)  I wanted to make sure we understood the question (maybe I missunderstood) and that your response has no effect on an inner join.